# What does "<<" in "1000 << 16" mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, int, operators

What does "<<" in "1000 << 16" mean in ruby?

I know that for strings `<<` can be used for concatenation, but I don't understand what it does for `int`s. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [left shift bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift).

Answer (score 3):

What it should do is take the binary representation of one thousand and shift the bits to the left sixteen spaces. Effectively, it multiplies the number by 65,536.

Answer (score 2):

You can look it up in RDoc: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001102

> fix << count → integer
>
> Shifts fix left count positions (right
>   if count is negative).